# Form wont validate, says that all fields are empty Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In a view I have 3 forms:

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['subtitle', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'tags', 'body']
        widgets = {
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'log-body editable'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'tags-field', 'class': 'log-form-field'}),
            'latitude': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'latitude-field', 'class': 'log-form-field'}),
            'longitude': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'longitude-field', 'class': 'log-form-field'}),
            'subtitle': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'subtitle-field', 'class': 'log-form-field'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'subtitle': 'Subtitle:',
            'tags': 'Tags:',
            'latitude': 'Latitude',
            'longitude': 'Longitude',
            'body': ''
        }


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    images = forms.ImageField(label='Images', widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
        attrs={
            'multiple': True,
            'class': 'file-upload',
            'id': 'file-upload-button-image',
            'name': 'images'}
    )
                              )

    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ('images',)


class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    videos = forms.FileField(label='Videos', widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
        attrs={
            'multiple': True,
            'class': 'file-upload',
            'id': 'file-upload-button-video',
            'name': 'images'
        }
    )
                             )

    class Meta:
        model = PostVideo
        fields = ('videos',)
```

And I have a template that creates a post and stores the videos and pictures and that works great. Where I'm having a hard time is updating a 'Post'.

```
class PostEditView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Logging/edit view.html'
    post_form_class = PostForm
    image_form_class = ImageForm
    video_form_class = VideoForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        context['post_form'] = PostForm(instance=Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']))
        context['image_form'] = ImageForm(empty_permitted=True, use_required_attribute=False)
        context['video_form'] = VideoForm(empty_permitted=True, use_required_attribute=False)
        context['images'] = PostImage.objects.filter(post_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['videos'] = PostVideo.objects.filter(post_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        post_data = request.POST or None
        if post_data.get('Delete'):
            if len(post_data.getlist('img-index[]')) > 0:
                for i in post_data.getlist('img-index[]'):
                    PostImage.objects.filter(id=i).delete()
            if len(post_data.getlist('vid-index[]')) > 0:
                for i in post_data.getlist('vid-index[]'):
                    PostVideo.objects.filter(id=i).delete()
        print(post_data)
        post_form = PostForm(data=post_data, instance=Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']), prefix='post')
        print(post_form.is_bound)
        post_form.is_valid()
        print(post_form.errors)
        images = request.FILES.getlist('image-images')
        videos = request.FILES.getlist('video-videos')
        if post_form.is_valid():
            print('valid form')
            for i in images:
                instance = PostImage(image=i, post=context['post_pk'])
                instance.save()
            for v in videos:
                instance = PostVideo(video=v, post=context['post_pk'])
                instance.save()

        return super(PostEditView, self).render_to_response(context)

    def form_save(self, form, request):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.author = request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name
        obj.event_type = 'Log Entry'
        obj.save()
        messages.success(self.request, "{} posted successfully".format(obj))
        return obj
```

When I call `is_valid()` on `post_form` it always says false, although it does say its bound. My post object does contain the data from the form in my template, including a csrf token, but for some reason the form is never valid and says that all the fields are empty.

from `print(post_data)`:

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['h5uxuACKsvBcO4lrPB7yKbYgr0BsASEklT3GTp6R3t8na13TadAfjbihl2VyGvdC'], 'subtitle': ['Test with photos'], 'latitude': ['48.000'], 'longitude': ['112.000'], 'tags': ['[]'], 'images': [''], 'videos': [''], 'body': ['<p>body test 2 saa</p>']}>`
from `print(post_form.is_bound)`:

`True`

from `print(post_form.errors)`:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
<li>subtitle<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>latitude
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>longitude
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>tags
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li
></ul></li><li>body
<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        active = 'Active'
        inactive = 'Inactive'

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='Log Entry: ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=6)
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    body = models.TextField()
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EventType.choices, default='Log Entry', editable=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Status.choices, default='Active')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Post by: ' + str(self.user) + " on: " + self.post_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")


def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.post.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_media/%s/%s" % (slug, filename)


class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename, verbose_name='Image')

    def filename(self):
        return self.image.name.split('/')[-1]


class PostVideo(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=get_image_filename, verbose_name='Video')

    def filename(self):
        return self.video.name.split('/')[-1]
```

template:

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block titleblock %}New Log{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
    <script src="{% static 'Logging/js/medium-editor.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Logging/css/medium-editor.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Logging/css/new_post.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyblock %}
    <form class="post-form" id="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action=".">
        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to delete these items?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete" value="1"  form="post-form">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in post_form %}
                    {% ifnotequal field.label '' %}
                        <div class="input">
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field }}
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    {% endifnotequal %}
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 button-col">
                <label for="file-upload-button-image" class="custom-file-upload">
                    <div class="upload-button-wrapper">
                    {{ image_form.images }}
                        <p id="image-num"></p>
                        <img src="{% static 'layout/img/image.svg' %}" alt="svg" id="img-svg">
                        <img src="{% static 'layout/img/plus-circle.svg' %}" alt="svg+" id="plus-svg">

                </div></label>
                <label for="file-upload-button-video" class="custom-file-upload">
                    <div class="upload-button-wrapper">
                    {{ video_form.videos }}
                        <p id="video-num"></p>
                        <img src="{% static 'layout/img/film.svg' %}" alt="svg" id="img-svg">
                        <img src="{% static 'layout/img/plus-circle.svg' %}" alt="svg+" id="plus-svg">
                </div></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 edit-col">
        <div class="images_existing">
            {% for image in images %}
                <div class="stacker">
                <div class="image-selector-wrapper">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="img-index[]" class="invisible img-checkboxes" value="{{ image.pk }}">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.filename }}">
                    <h6>{{ image.filename }}</h6>
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <div class="num-indicator" id="image-number"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        <div class="button-box">
        <button type="submit" name="download" value="1" class="btn-primary">Download</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div><div class="edit" id="edit-images">Edit</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 edit-col">
        <div class="videos_existing">
            {% for video in videos %}
                <div class="stacker">
                <div class="video-selector-wrapper">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="vid-index[]" value="{{ video.pk }}" class="invisible video-cb">
                    <img class="thumbnail-video" src="{% static 'layout/img/film.svg' %}" alt="{{ video.filename }}">
                    <h6>{{ video.filename }}</h6>
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <div class="num-indicator" id="video-number"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div></div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div><div class="edit" id="edit-video">Edit</div>
        </div></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ post_form.body }}
                    <button type="submit" class="custom-submit-button"><img src="{% static 'layout/img/upload.svg' %}" alt="submit"> <span>Submit</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% if post_form.errors %}
        {% for field in post_form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in post_form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    </form>
<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
<script src="{% static 'Logging/js/new_post.js' %}"></script>


{% endblock %}
```

I can not for the life of my figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You add a prefix to your form in the post method but not in your get_context_data method so it’s not set on the GET

Comment: You're my hero, thank you!